# Would it be possible to harness the energy flow from a continuous water system?

Tags: turbines, renewable-energy, hydrodynamics

I’m working on a project to put Archimedes screw turbines into drains and sewerage water. However, as an experimental project I wanted to test out an idea to evaluating turbine degrees and flow rate effects. Would it be possible to build a continuous flow system like the image I’ve uploaded. (You’re not supposed to be able to have continuous motion) -could the system be enhance if I use a solar pump. Would the system envisaged offer useful power output? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Perpetual motion machines never work, however hard you try.  You can't get more energy out of the water flowing down than you spent pumping it up in the first place.

You could keep the machine going using a solar panel to top up the power.  Though from an energy harvesting point-of-view, you'd be better off throwing away all the water mechanism, and keeping the solar panel.

But if you're testing the efficiency of different water powered power generators, it may be a useful thing to do.